# How to install code blocks in kali?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

First thing first - I am pretty much new to linux based operating system. Please be patient with me.

Hi,
I recently installed kali on my computer. But I dont know the basics of this OS. Please help me to install code::blocks.

Here is what i did:

- I downloaded codeblocks-13.12-1.amd64.debian.stable.tar.xz file from internet.
- when I extracted it I found many (16) .deb files. (I assume that I have to install every single file)
- when I tried to install it all with package installer by right clicking it I got a error "The action is not supported by this backend."
- when I used "apt-get install codeblocks_13.12-1_amd64.deb" (it is the first .deb file among the 16 I extracted) in terminal I got the errors "E: unable to locate package codeblocks_13.12-1_amd64.deb" "E: couldn't find any package by regex 'codeblocks_13.12-1_amd64.deb'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://playtowatch.com/watch/75UZ5ScW_TM/how-to-install-codeblocks-on-linux-kali-linux.html

I had the same problem and followed the tutorial below the video.

First download the wxwidgets source for linux. Then download the codeblocks source: `codeblocks_13.12-1.tar.gz` (instead of the debian package you downloaded). Links to both of these can be found at the bottom of the page linked above.

Go to your downloads folder, right click on each of the files, and click *Extract here*. The tutorial in the link above explains how to extract the files in the terminal but I had problems extracting the codeblocks file so just did it like I would in Windows.

Open a terminal (I did the rest of this in root. Im not sure if this is necessary because I am also new to linux but thats what I did. You can switch to root by typing "su" in the terminal) and navigate to where you downloaded and extracted the wxwidgets. Type the following commands:

```
cd /home/USERNAME/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.0.2/

./configure

make

make install

ldconfig
```

Once all that is finished navigate to the codeblocks folder that you extracted:

```
cd /home/USERNAME/Downloads/codeblocks-13.12/

./configure

make

make install

ldconfig
```